# Unity Animation Glitches in Build

Tags: android, animation, unity-game-engine

I have a character in my game that carries an umbrella and briefcase. The umbrella and briefcase are both part of the character's rig and he animates and looks great inside the editor and standalone PC builds (see example below). The character also has an animation where he opens up the umbrella. I am using mecanim.

[image: Working Umbrella]

However when I publish a Web, Android or iOS build, the umbrella gets stuck in a weird half open state like the below:

[image: Broken Umbrella]

And it opens fully in animation loops where it shouldn't.

There's no compression turned on that I can see, and I've exhausted all my ideas on why it would do this. But put simply, it works in the editor and in standalone PC builds, so why not in a Web, Android or iOS build?

**Edit - I'm using Unity Pro, version 4.3.4f1**

**Edit 2 - Tested in the PC Standalone build and it works fine**

**Edit 3 - Wasted a bounty on this issue and I'm still no closer to fixing it, I'm now thinking of submitting a bug report to Unity.**

Any hints would be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks

Comment: Any difference if you export and build the project using Eclipse/IntelliJ/Android Studio?

Comment: Do you also get the problem on PC standalone build or is this specific to Web, Android and iOS? also it seems you are not alone : http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/443000/unity-build-for-ios-using-xcode-broken-animation.html?sort=oldest

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that tbh @shoerat, and also would that work for iOS builds?

Comment: @Tom the PC Standalone build works fine actually, it's just the web/iOS/Android builds. Does that shed any more light on the issue? (Have updated the question)

Comment: Go to `File -> Build Settings: Android`, check `Google Android Project` and export. Then import the project in Eclipse and build. I am not sure about the other builds...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! At last!!

The cause was that under Edit > Project Settings > Quality, the "Blend Weights" option was set to "1 Bone", I upped it to "2 Bones" and voila! Problem solved!

[image: Project Settings > Quality]

Answer (score 1):

This have been happening to me since I updated to **Unity 4.3.4f1**. Animations work perfect in the Editor however they fail when I build the apk file to Android.

I don't know if it is related  to my OS (Windows 8.1 x64) or not but **I solve it saving my project and restarting Unity editor**.

For now I will keep doing this till they fix this bug in the next release.

Comment: So you save, restart Unity, then make a build? And this solves it for you?

Comment: yes. I also noticed that my apk size decreases somewhat when that happens. Also I only noticed problems with the animations state machines