# Unity3D - My games working fine on Editor, acting strange on mobile device and emulator

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

i always choose optimize game objects for all my 3d models on rig options. When i remove this, all problems gone :) I am not sure it is wrong or a bug.

thank you @CarbineCoder for help!

Comment: player settings: http://oi68.tinypic.com/n1vtzd.jpg

Comment: Try googling the term `unity3d game glitches for android`, the problem you define is too generic to offer any solution. There are lot of posts under this search query. Something might click for you.

Comment: @CarbineCoder thank you for answer. I am figting this issue almost a week. I did lots of googling but can't find a solution.

Comment: Sad to know. Rather than attacking it as a whole. Try stripping down the component to bare minimum into a new scene. E.g. The character alone  should be in the scene and try to reproduce the bug. Then you would be able to eliminate the possibilities. e.g. this problem - http://stackoverflow.com/a/23683773/442444

Comment: Glad to know. What was the issue? can you post it as an answer... I am interested to know as well :)

Comment: i will edit the first post, i always choose optimize game objects for all my 3d models on rig options. When i remove this, all problems gone :) I am not sure it is wrong or a bug. What do you think ?

Comment: No idea :P, looks like couple of people have faced this issue as well... reasons might differ.